# How to get back the result from Child activity to Parent in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I'am starting a child activity on click of a button from Parent. And i'am calculating some result (of type string) in child activity and finishing the child to come back to Parent. Is there any better way to get that result in Parent using intents or extras? (I can get that result in Parent by making the result variable as public & static in Child) Please help me. I'am a newbie to android development.

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ChildActivity.class), ACTIVITY_CONSTANT);
```

What should i write in onActivityResult() of Parent?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Instead of `startActivityForResult(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, ChildActivity.class), ACTIVITY_CONSTANT);`

You can use putExtras() method to pass values between activities:

In Child Activity:

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("myData1", "Data 1 value");
data.putExtra("myData2", "Data 2 value");
// Activity finished ok, return the data
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

And in Parent activity, you can override onActivityResult() and inside that you can have Intent paramater and from the Intent parameter of this method you can retrieve the extra values passed from the child activity, such as intent.getStringExtra or intent.getSerializableExtra.

for example:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data.hasExtra("myData1")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, data.getExtras().getString("myData1"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i return the result from Child to Parent ?
Your answer works well if i want to pass values from Parent to Child. But i need to finish my child activity after calculating the result in child and return the result to parent.

Comment: @SANDHYA please check updated code. You have to use setResult() method to pass data from child to parent.

Comment: After called setResult(...); you need to call finish(); to close the "child" activity.

Comment: @ThomasDecaux Have included `finish()` method. Thanks for pointing out the required things.

Comment: What is REQUEST_CODE?

Comment: In this case REQUEST_CODE is ACTIVITY_CONSTANT from example.

Comment: Hello @PareshMayani sir in my case when i am calling setResult from my library its not receiving at my main app.

Answer (score 4):

In Parent Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourChildActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CONSTANT);
```

in child activity to sent back result of your parent activity through

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("key1", "value1");
data.putExtra("key2", "value2");
// Activity finished return ok, return the data
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

and get child activity result information in your parent activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data.hasExtra("key1") && data.hasExtra("key2")) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Your reult is :  "data.getExtras().getString("key1") + " " + data.getExtras().getString("key2"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```