# Make an activity run some code based on the result of another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, handler

Activity A starts Activity B.

I need a way to get Activity B return to Activity A a success/fail code based on the result of  some operations, so Activity A can execute some other operations (IE: B is a signup page on some services. A starts B from a button and, after B signs up correctly, sends to A username and password to autologin on that service).

I can't use handler since they're not Parcelable neither Serializable, so I can't put a handler to Activity A in the Extra when I start Activity B. Any other way to make them comunicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

For that you need to start activity for result.

You can check out this answer for guildline:
[on activity result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582314/how-to-get-back-the-result-from-child-activity-to-parent-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use intents:

while going to the otherActivity pass data by..

`intent.putExtra("Title", datatitle);
intent.putExtra("Content", your data);
startActivity(intent);`

and to recover it in second activity use:

title= getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title");

Answer (score 0):

You can use intents for this :

From Activity A call

Intent in = new Intent(context,ActivityB.class);

in.putExtra("value",value);

startActivity(in);

And from Activity B get the values from Activity A

in = getIntents();

in.getExtra("value",value);

Comment: The problem is that A starts B and needs B result to continue, B doesn't need A in order to execute its tasks. @Sandy 's solutions seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Cusy So that means .. you have to start A again after B?