# Going back to parent activity from any other child activity without reload

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mapview

I have a MapView in the MainActivity. User can roam maps. There are many activities. I want to go back to MainActivity from any activity that can be third or fourth level activity. I am following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10582579/1357214). It is a solution to go back from second activity to Parent with data. But when I am trying to go back to parent from 3rd or 4th activity `finish()` will not work as it will return previous activity. So I have started the parent activity with `startActivity(mainIntent)`. The problem is its reloading the MapView from its start, the parent Intent is reloading. How can I pass data from third or fourth activity to parent without reloading the MapView?

Comment: just use finish(); to finish child activity so previous activity wil load

Comment: finish() will reload the previous. From third activity finish() will return to second activity not the Parent Activity.

Answer (score 2):

```
mainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Worked!!!